# Problems with node_modules folder with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-modules, npm-install

I have an issue with the node_modules folder with Grunt on my new laptop.

Attached are 2 screenshots, one is correct and how my folders look on my iMac which I have used for years, the other is how the folder structure looks on my new laptop. It seem's it is putting all grunt folder's in the root and not putting them in different folders.

I am doing the normal cd/ into the folder then writing 'npm install'.

It is working and no issues really but something is not right, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

```html
{
  "name": "NameHere",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.7.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-datauri": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-includes": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-spritesmith": "~1.26.0",
    "grunt-svg2png": "~0.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your json file ?

Comment: Sorry, I should've done this. I have copied and pasted what is in my package.json file within the root of the folder I am working in. Thanks